# Skip Sat and Sunday and get the date by from the current date in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am using the following code to skip the sat and sunday to get only the working days for a particular number of hours, actually what is my task:

I have a project and specific time to complete that, now i just want to show the date when the project will be complete.:

My code is:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    Int32 d = 1;
    Int32 result = 260 / 8;
    for (d = 0; d <= result; d++)
    {
        if (date.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Saturday" || date.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday")
        {
            d = d - 1;
            date = date.AddDays(1);
        }
        else
        {
            date = date.AddDays(1);
        }
    }
    lbldate.Text = date.ToString();
```

Its working fine upto 30 days when days are 32 then date should come is :: 25th nov 2013
but it is coming 26th nov 2013.

please tell me where i am making mistake.

Comment: On my opinion, you should retrieve working days (also set holydays) from database. There are plenty examples how to create a table with the working days. Then create a scalar function to get the working day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's something more elegant, but it works and doesn't need a loop:

```
public static DateTime GetDateIn(int numWorkingHours)
{
    int numDays = numWorkingHours / 8;
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    // normalize to monday
    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        date = date.AddDays(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 1 : 2); 
    int weeks = numDays / 5;
    int remainder = numDays % 5;
    date = date.AddDays(weeks * 7 + remainder);  
    // normalize to monday
    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        date = date.AddDays(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 1 : 2);    
    return date;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/kSE469)</kbd>

Comment: By the way, on ideone `DateTime.Now` is `10/14/2013 5:43:57 PM`. That's the reason for the "wrong" result.

Answer (score 1):

A working solution would be:

```
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;
double remainingAmountOfWorkingDays = Math.Round(260d / 8d);
while (remainingAmountOfWorkingDays > 0)
  {
    endDate = endDate.AddDays(1);

    if (endDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || endDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
       continue;

    Console.WriteLine(remainingAmountOfWorkingDays +" "+endDate.ToString("dddd dd.MM.yyyy"));
    remainingAmountOfWorkingDays--;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subtracting from the d variable

use the following Code in case it's a Holiday Sat or Sun

```
date.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)); // where 1 is day count you need to subtract
```